# Why is Junk Email still delivered to the Inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

I have backed up outlook `pst` files from Outlook 2007 and imported the `pst` files  to Outlook 2010, but Junk Email still delivered to the inbox.

I have set my Junk E-mail Filter level to `High` and still all spam is being delivered to my inbox. Currently using upgrade Windows 8.

Comment: Did you export the blocked sender list from the previous version of Outlook and import it into the new version?